# (Swift) What API Implementation is Used for Background Timers?

Tags: swift, timer, background, countdown

Consider an app like Clash Royale (and countless others) that has a reward countdown timer that generates rewards or other in-game currency every so often, how is that done?

My current process is to get the current date and time from google and upload it to the user’s data in Firebase when the app enters any kind of background state (or terminates), and then upon re-launching the app it read the current date and time again and compares it to the old value in Firebase... Then I do some math to figure out what the timer should be at AND how much currency has been earned during the lapsed time... But this feels SUPER clanky.

Is there something else that can handle this sort of background countdown?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like the right approach to me and I have done something similar in the past. I would proceed the way you have it until somebody can give a better answer...

Comment: Thanks for your input! Learning Swift has been very fun but it's like floating in the ocean on a dingy... not really knowing direction. Even simple responses like this help affirm that I'm pointed in the right direction at least haha. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mohit. I see no major problems with your design. There are ways to defeat it by hacking the program directly, but this is true of every solution. Yours is simple, elegant, and effective against most simple attacks (addressing complex attacks is *much* harder, and may not be worth it). It would definitely be my first choice.

I would recommend certificate pinning. Otherwise it is somewhat easy to trick your program into reading the wrong time server. Certificate pinning tells your app to only trust a specific HTTPS certificate or group of certificates, rather than just every cert trusted by the device. For an intro, see [Certificate Pinning](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E57-certificate-pinning). For an ObjC implementation to simplify it, see [CertificateValidator](https://github.com/rnapier/CertificateValidator/blob/master/CertificateValidator/CertificateValidator.swift).

The one usability problem with your approach is that it requires a network connection in order to function at all. If the user doesn't have network access, do you prevent them from using the program (perhaps this is already true for other reasons), or do you assume their local clock is correct (this probably would defeat the entire purpose).

If offline access is desirable, a tool you can leverage is `mach_absolute_time`. This is more complicated to use, and is more difficult to secure than your approach, but it can work offline. `mach_absolute_time` returns a monotonically increasing clock. That is to say, it always goes up at a constant rate, even if the user modifies the system clock. It is not in seconds, however. You need to use `AbsoluteToDuration` to convert it. (See [QA1398](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html) for details.) It resets when the device is rebooted. In principle, you can compare the time it provides to the time the system clock provides to determine if the system clock appears trustworthy, and if so, you can award points while offline. Whether this is worth the extra work (and it still can have false negatives) depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes the one downside would be network dependency, although I'm kind of gearing towards just requiring it anyway... makes the world an easier place for managing my data. I'm using UTC from google's servers as well (in case that's relevant lol). Your suggestions for offline usability is very appreciated and I'll definitely look into that as well!

Comment: Yes, you'll definitely want to do all your work in UTC; it just keeps things much simpler if all you care about is the difference between two points in time.

Comment: @RobNapier I started my iOS career by reading your book, iOS 6 Pushing your liimts and I am honored to have you agree with my solution :) .. Sorry but didn't know of any other means to say thank you! (Could've used twitter ;))

Answer (score 0):

The Foundation library contains a `Timer` class which you can read the documentation for [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer).

It provides an API for firing off work after a certain amount of time has elapsed. The constructor method you want use is:

`class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, block: (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer`

(because the other version uses Selectors, and who wants to write kludgy Objective-C when they're writing Swift, if they can avoid it?)

So, for an example, let's say you have

1. a label `secondsLeftLabel` that shows the seconds left
2. a function `timesUp()` you want to call once it completes

First you'd need  to create a timer property and a secondsLeftInTimer property:

```
private var timer: Timer?
private var secondsLeftInTimer: Double = 0
```

Then you could implement a function like this:

```
func setUpTimer(numberOfSeconds: Double) {
    secondsLeftInTimer = numberOfSeconds
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] (_) in
        self?.secondElapsed()
    }
}
```

You'll see I created a helper function, which you'd implement something like this:

```
func secondElapsed() {
    secondsLeftInTimer -= 1
    secondsLeftLabel.text = "\(secondsLeftInTimer) seconds left"

    if secondsLeftInTimer <= 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        timesUp()
    }
}
```

Also, if you want that function to only take in whole seconds, you can also modify those first two lines like this:

```
func setUpTimer(numberOfSeconds: Int) {
    secondsLeftInTimer = Double(exactly: numberOfSeconds)
```

Comment: `Timer` only runs while you're in the foreground. I don't believe it would be very effective for the kind of use case described here.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize at first that you meant truly background (like while the app is backgrounded), so my other answer won't work. For what you want to do, this is the proper use case for a scheduled UNNotification.

From iOS 10 onward, you can schedule a local notification with custom triggers. One such trigger is a time interval. You'd do something like this:

```
func scheduleNotificationAfter(numberOfSeconds: Double) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Time's up!"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: numberOfSeconds, repeats: false)

    let notification = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Times Up Notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notification, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: I haven't gotten to the point yet of researching and implementing notifications in my app, but this is fantastic! I'll for sure come back to this further down the road... Looks very simple. Thanks!

Comment: I’m glad you like it, but I guess I don’t understand what you’re looking for, because this seems like the answer to your question. This will give you an event that is triggered after a predefined period of time, and will run completely in the background. What is missing that you need?

Comment: Oh I see, hmmm... I read it as being more for notifications (like when you get the little banners on lock screen). Where, for instance, when the app is closed, the remaining seconds are sent to that "scheduleNotificationAfter(numberOfSeconds: Double)" function and then after that amount of time, a banner (notification) informs the user that... for example... "Time's Up!". I guess a few questions are: 1) When that timer runs out, can it trigger other functions / update variables even while in the background? 2) What happens when the device is shut off?

Comment: Yes. You us usually implement a notification delegate that handles the receipt of notifications.